# How to extract arrays in a state through React.createContext ();?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to extract arrays in a state through `React.createContext();`

This is my state

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      sideDrawerOpen: false,
      resultData:[
        {id:"1",desc:"Dining",img:dining},
        {id:"2",desc:"Wellness",img:wellness},
        {id:"3",desc:"Activities",img:activities},
        {id:"4",desc:"Dining",img:dining},
        {id:"5",desc:"Wellness",img:wellness},
        {id:"6",desc:"Activities",img:activities},
        {id:"7",desc:"Activities",img:activities}
      ],
      title:"lorem"
    }
  }
```

This is `MyContext.provider`

```
return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <Toolbar click={this.drawerButtonClickHandler} />
        {sideDrawer}
        {backdrop}
        <Banner />
        <HomeMenu data={this.state} />
        <Merchants />
        <Voucher />
        <br />
      </MyContext.Provider>
    )
```

I tried looping but it didn't work but if I release data from a state that isn't an array I can do it.

```
class HomeMenu extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <MyContext.Consumer>
        {(context) => (
          <p>{context.title}</p>
        )}
      </MyContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What you have tried in looping? Please provide that code.

Comment: this problem is finished I'm using static contextType (static contextType = MyContext)